# UserControl events in webform

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have an usercontrol which contains 3 buttons and 7 text boxes.I am calling that usercontrol dynamiclly in my webform using LoadControl.

But my problem here is

1.How to know which button(of user control) was clicked on my page?

2.How to raise those events?

Thanks
Kavitha

Comment: explain question 2, do you want a code example, if so, in what language (C# or VB).

Answer (score 2):

Create event in your user control and fire it when button is clicked. So, you can manage this event from main page.

For more info please look at [Easily Raise Events From ASP.NET ASCX User Controls](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2004/10/06/Easily-Raise-Events-From-ASP.NET-ASCX-User-Controls.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In your user control (WebUserControl1.ascx) you may have a Button1 with a click handler that acts like so:

```
Event Button1Click(ByVal button As Button)

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  RaiseEvent Button1Click(sender)
End Sub
```

And you can then dynamically attach an EventHandler to this in the parent control like so:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim buttonControl As WebUserControl1 = LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx")
    AddHandler buttonControl.Button1Click, AddressOf ControlEventHandler
End Sub

Private Sub ControlEventHandler(ByVal ctl As Control)
    'We now have access to this control's properties
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the events of the controls on your usercontrol in its own codebehind file and raise events on your usercontrol that can in turn get handled by the codebehind file of your page.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is for the user control to encapsulate the controls inside of it, and for it to then raise a meaningful event. For instance, I wrote a date picker user control that has a RadioButtonList to select between "Last 12 months",  "Year to date", or "Custom dates", and also start date and end date text boxes. My user control exposes a single DateChanged event, which it raises if a new radio button selection is made, or if the "Custom" selection is made and the input dates changed.

This way, the user of the control doesn't need to know about the complex implementation of the control. It just subscribes to the DateChanged event.

Comment: I would say it would be easier to just expose SelectedDate as a property rather than raising an event. Much less code

Comment: That's true except for the fact that data needs to be requeried when the date selection changes.